# How to check if a suspend function has completed executing

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

Hello I have a suspend function `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails()`, I want check if the function has been executed and once executed I want to call `success()` function.

I am unable to use `invokeOnCompletion`  on the function call

How can I do this please or what is the other way I can call `success()` function once `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` is executed

suspend function

```
suspend fun updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details: PersonalDetails) {
    userDao.get().collect { cachedUser ->
        val updatedCachedUser = UserDB(cachedUser.id, ...)
        userDao.save(updatedCachedUser)
    }
}
```

from viewmodel I want to call the above function and on success or invoke successfull I want to call success function

```
 userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details). invokeOnCompletion{

                        success()
}
```

Thanks
R

Comment: What about just: `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(); success()`? Assuming `userDao.get()` returns a flow, so `collect()` suspends until item(s) is collected, it should be fully synchronous.

Comment: Hello,     @Query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")
    fun get(): Flow<UserDB>
I tried updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(); success() but did not work

Comment: So, I assume you are using Room and while I'm not very familiar with it, I believe if you return a flow from your `get()`, you don't really get the user once. You create an infinite flow of changes to users. So first question is if this is really what you need? Because for this reason `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails()` does never really finish its work - it constantly observes users for changes. So do you need to invoke `success()` every time there is a new change? Or do you need to only get the user once and not observe the data for changes?

Comment: what I want to know is the function is executed, or user is updated then call success method

Comment: Then put `success()` inside `collect {}`.

Comment: it does not let me use collect like this 
 userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details).collect {
                            
                        }

Comment: I mean put it inside `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails()`. If I understand your case properly, `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails()` never finishes. It waits for changes forever, so you can't do anything after it finishes. If you would like to keep this function generic and decouple it from `success()` then you would need to return another flow from it or e.g. receive a function that will be called after each user change.

Comment: You DAO’s `get()` function returns a Flow. A Flow from a DAO is never completed because it monitors the database forever until the coroutine gets cancelled, so there is no successful completion state to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your function `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` never completes because the `Flow` returned by Room never completes (it monitors for DB changes forever).

Assuming you are interested only in the first change you can do:

```
suspend fun updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details: PersonalDetails) {
        val cachedUSer = userDao.get().first() // this will get the current value from the DB
        val updatedCachedUser = UserDB(cachedUser.id, ...)
        userDao.save(updatedCachedUser)
    }
```

Here `first()` gets the current value from the DB (or throws if it doesn't exist) and does NOT observe forever. Alternatively you can use `firstOrNull()`.

Then your other function becomes:

```
updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails()
success()
```